# how can i prepare mock test cases for httpresponse?

Tags: force.com

Here is the code -->

```
public Httpresponse SendXMLRequest(String XMLRequest)
    {
        String idOfInsertedUser = '';
        try
        {
            Boolean opSuccess = false;
            CommonManager cmgr = new CommonManager();
            string GAEUrl = cmgr.getGAEUrl();
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setEndpoint(GAEUrl);
            req.setMethod('POST');

            req.setBody('request='+XMLRequest);

            // Create a new http object to send the request object
            // A response object is generated as a result of the request
            Http http = new Http();
            Httpresponse res = http.send(req);
            return res;         
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionService.saveException(ex, 'UserManager', 'SendXMLRequest', null);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Here is the test case -->

```
public static testMethod void testSendXMLRequestMethod() {
        // Set mock callout class
        Test.startTest(); 
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new TestMockHttpResponseGenerator());

        // Call method to test.
        // This causes a fake response to be sent
        // from the class that implements HttpCalloutMock. 
        String XML = 'xmlBody';
        **HttpResponse res = testUserManager.SendXMLRequest(XML);**
        Test.stopTest();
        // Verify response received contains fake values
        String contentType = res.getHeader('Content-Type');
        System.assert(contentType == 'application/json');
        String actualValue = res.getBody();
        String expectedValue = 'request='+XML;
        System.assertEquals(actualValue, expectedValue);
        System.assertEquals(200, res.getStatusCode());
    }
```

In this above code line

```
HttpResponse res = testUserManager.SendXMLRequest(XML);
```

is giving following error
**System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out**

Comment: it is advisable to start writing some test class code rather than waiting for someone to write the code for you from scratch. Can you do that?

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this, lot of examples might help you

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex_testing.htm

Comment: Is there any video tutorial available for this mock test ? please give me that link too.

Comment: @AmitAgrawal unfortunately there is no video tutorial available.